# How to determine regular subgroup

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, group-actions, normal-subgroups

I understand this has to do with the structure of p-groups.

- Let $G$ be a group acting transitively on a set $X$ where  $|X|=p^{n+1}$.
- Suppose that there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ acting transitively on $X$ and that $|H|=p^{n+2}$. The stabiliser $H_x$ of a point $x$ in $H$ is such that it is not normal in $H$ and that $|H_x|=p$.

I don't know how this information can enable me arrive at a conclusion to the following question:

Prove that $G$ has no subgroup that acts regularly on $X$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: "No-clue" questions still need context. Consider answering the following questions in an [edit]: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: What is $n$ defined as?

Comment: Could you please remind us what a regular action is?

Comment: Why are you asking for help in proving something that is not true?

Comment: @Cpc Why don't you just search for "regular group action"?

Comment: Well I of course could.   But it seems like a good idea for the OP to give the definition. Either way. @DerekHolt

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: take $G=H=D_4$, the dihedral group of order $8$ acting naturally on $4$ points. (So $p=2$ and $n=1$.) The stabiliser has order $2$ and is not normal, but there are regular subgroups.